# OSGi ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, osgi

I am trying to run the example from Modular Java book and facing a ClassNotFoundException. The gist of the error is the I have 2 bundles.

Bundle 1 is called Index. 
Bundle 2 is a wrapped bundle of Compass project.

Bundle 1 uses Bundle 2 and has the packages which it uses from Bundle 2 declared in "Import-Package" header in its manifest. The same packages are exported by Bundle 2 as well.

Classes of Bundle 2 used by Index (Bundle 1), call few more classes which are internal to Bundle 2. The packages of these classes are exported by Bundle 2 as well. But whenever I deploy these on Felix (Using Pax-runner), the start fails with the following error.

```
[FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG main-findmyjar.index - BundleEvent STOPPED - main-findmyjar.index
ERROR: Bundle main-findmyjar.index [7] Error starting file:bundles/main-findmyjar.index_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle main-findmyjar.index [7].)
org.compass.core.config.ConfigurationException: Failed to instantiate [org.compass.core.config.binding.metadata.AsmMetaDataReader], please verify class type at setting [compass.scanner.reader]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.compass.core.config.binding.metadata.AsmMetaDataReader
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.compass.core.config.binding.metadata.AsmMetaDataReader
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.compass.core.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:90)
        at org.compass.core.config.CompassSettings.getSettingAsInstance(CompassSettings.java:304)
        at org.compass.core.config.binding.metadata.MetaDataReaderFactory.getMetaDataReader(MetaDataReaderFactory.java:35)
        at org.compass.core.config.binding.AbstractClassMetaDataMappingBinding.setUpBinding(AbstractClassMetaDataMappingBinding.java:24)
        at org.compass.annotations.config.binding.AnnotationsMappingBinding.setUpBinding(AnnotationsMappingBinding.java:93)
        at org.compass.core.config.CompassMappingBinding.setUpBinding(CompassMappingBinding.java:56)
        at org.compass.core.config.CompassConfiguration.getMappingBinding(CompassConfiguration.java:121)
        at org.compass.core.config.CompassConfiguration.addClass(CompassConfiguration.java:500)
        at org.gt.osgi.findmyjar.index.internal.Activator.getCompass(Activator.java:40)
        at org.gt.osgi.findmyjar.index.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:35)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1977)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG main-findmyjar.index - FrameworkEvent ERROR - main-findmyjar.index
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle main-findmyjar.index [7].
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2027)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.compass.core.config.ConfigurationException: Failed to instantiate [org.compass.core.config.binding.metadata.AsmMetaDataReader], please verify class type at setting [compass.scanner.reader]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.compass.core.config.binding.metadata.AsmMetaDataReader
        at org.compass.core.config.CompassSettings.getSettingAsInstance(CompassSettings.java:306)
        at org.compass.core.config.binding.metadata.MetaDataReaderFactory.getMetaDataReader(MetaDataReaderFactory.java:35)
        at org.compass.core.config.binding.AbstractClassMetaDataMappingBinding.setUpBinding(AbstractClassMetaDataMappingBinding.java:24)
        at org.compass.annotations.config.binding.AnnotationsMappingBinding.setUpBinding(AnnotationsMappingBinding.java:93)
        at org.compass.core.config.CompassMappingBinding.setUpBinding(CompassMappingBinding.java:56)
        at org.compass.core.config.CompassConfiguration.getMappingBinding(CompassConfiguration.java:121)
        at org.compass.core.config.CompassConfiguration.addClass(CompassConfiguration.java:500)
        at org.gt.osgi.findmyjar.index.internal.Activator.getCompass(Activator.java:40)
        at org.gt.osgi.findmyjar.index.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:35)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1977)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.compass.core.config.binding.metadata.AsmMetaDataReader
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.compass.core.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:90)
        at org.compass.core.config.CompassSettings.getSettingAsInstance(CompassSettings.java:304)
        ... 14 more
[FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG org.apache.felix.framework - BundleEvent STARTED - org.apache.felix.framework
[FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG org.apache.felix.framework - FrameworkEvent STARTED - org.apache.felix.framework
```

Any clues of what could be the problem ?

Here's the manifest.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: org.gt.osgi.findmyjar.index;uses:="org.gt.osgi.findmyj
ar.domain";version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT"
Private-Package: org.gt.osgi.findmyjar.index.internal
Ignore-Package: org.gt.osgi.findmyjar.index.internal   
Built-By: tyagig
Tool: Bnd-0.0.255
Bundle-Name: main-findmyjar.index
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_32
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Bnd-LastModified: 1357910690482
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Activator: org.gt.osgi.findmyjar.index.internal.Activator
Bundle-Description: Generated using Pax-Construct
Bundle-SymbolicName: main-findmyjar.index
Import-Package: org.compass.core,org.compass.core.config,org.compass.c
ore.config.binding.metadata,org.gt.osgi.findmyjar.domain;version="1.0
.0.SNAPSHOT",org.gt.osgi.findmyjar.index;version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT",org
.osgi.framework
```

Comment: Can we see manifest for bundle1 AND bundle2?

Comment: Found some more information here. When Bundle 1 calls classes of Bundle2 they internally try to load a class using Class.forName(). Could it be that while loading this, Class.forName() is still using classloader from first bundle.

Comment: Hmm Im not sure, the Manifest you posted, is that Bundle 1 or 2? Can you post both Manifests?

Answer (score 3):

It seems as if you have a org.compass.core.util.ClassUtils, which does a Class.forName(), which cascades the problem.

If ClassUtils is in bundle 2 and it is not given an explicit classloader to use, it will default to the bundles classloader. The bundleclassloader can only instantiate classes visible to bundle2 (In the entire class graph).

It is rather likely that the setting it is trying to load could be a class specified in bundle1, which is not visible.

Solution is to pass the classloader from bundle1 into bundle2 when it comes to dynamically loading classes or looking at classloader buddying mechanisms. There is an old [article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/eclipse-vms/) which might explain this a bit clearer.